# Apple ID: how best to move iTunes match and Apple Music to a different Apple ID

Tags: itunes, icloud, apple-id, itunes-match

I have two Apple IDs - from 2 different countries (one in EU, the other non-EU). Through a quirk of history one has iCloud 1(EU) and the other one 2(non-EU) has iTunes match and Apple Music, which I wish to move to 1(EU). What is the most logical and safest way to do this… Without losing any music (Edit: I have no purchased songs) or having any other issues? Does moving 'across borders' trigger anything unexpected?
Many thanks in advance for any advice.

Edit: I am mostly concerned about the hiatus between cancelling one sub (2) before starting the other (1)
Matched tracks can be kept if downloaded and saved, is that right?

Comment: Define 'move'. You cannot transfer subscriptions or purchases between IDs.

Comment: I mean move the subscription to other ID - I'm aware of the general non-transfer of media between IDs (syndication between country jurisdictions a difficulty too). I have no purchased music ( i have matched music), but going forward I wish to use just account 1(EU).

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question: iTunes Match/Apple Music will be avaible on the EU Apple ID as soon as you enable/pay for it, so switching may just involve signing out with the non-EU one and signing in with the EU one. What do I miss?

Comment: @nohillside That deals with subscriptions - what about media that has been bought in iTunes

Comment: @mmmmmm The OP says in a comment that they "have no purchased music", this probably should go into the question though. And of course they loose all matched tracks.

Comment: Given the challenges, why do you want to change the account you use for Music in the first place? I'm using two different accounts for ages now, without any problems so far.

Comment: @nohillside because... I'm having to maintain two bank accounts in different countries. Poor management of IDs has left me with iOS apps on both IDs and every time I have to update some apps (from (2), I have to log out and lose all my playlists, songs, etc in Music from (1). Re logging in then means everything gets downloaded again - this is really inconvenient when on-the-road - like 100Gb inconvenient..
Having said all that...I think just duplicating, transferring everything and checking then cancelling subs on (2) is probably best...as you suggested earlier.